# Как преобразовать строку в список из одного элемента?

Tags: python

Есть строка phone = '70000000'
Как преобразовать её в список вида phone = ['70000000']

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```py
phone = '70000000'
phone = [phone]
print(phone)
```

Вывод:

```
['70000000']
```